# How to use mozilla Rhino behind firewall?

Tags: javascript, proxy, firewall, rhino

Normally if I run the following the following command in the rhino shell,

```
mbp001:rhino1_7R2 user$ java -jar js.jar 
Rhino 1.7 release 2 2009 03 22
js> readUrl("http://www.google.com")
```

It will return the resultant html markups. However, if I runs it behind a firewall, it will throw an exception (because it is unable to reach the host)

How can I make the Rhino shell aware of the proxy? Is there any -D switch for this purpose?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

have you tried the standard java system properties "http.proxyHost" and "http.proxyPort"?

command line would be:

```
java -Dhttp.proxyHost=proxy.bigcorp.com -Dhttp.proxyPort=9000 -jar js.jar
```

Comment: Great! It just fixed my problem!